# Can not get presentment_currencies from Shopify admin rest API

Tags: shopify, shopify-api-node

I'm following the [doc](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2022-04/resources/product#get-products) to get products with `presentment_currencies`.
However, although I have set TWD & USD as currencies in my store.
Still can not get the data from Shopify API.

I'm using nodejs and the code below:

```
const client: any = new ShopifyAPI.Shopify.Clients.Rest(
      shopName,
      accessToken
    );

client.get({
    path: 'products',
    query: {
        presentment_currencies: 'TWD,USD',
    },
})
```

The return data still don't have `presentment_currencies`.

Answer (score 2):

I found that we should add an extra headers on the API header.
So, the correct code will be:

```
client.get({
          path: 'products',
          query: {
            presentment_currencies: 'TWD,USD',
          },
          extraHeaders: {
            'X-Shopify-Api-Features': 'include-presentment-prices',
          },
        })
```

I found the extra headers [here](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-sdks/retrieving-variant-s-presentment-prices-via-the-api/td-p/612957).

Comment: I think you are dreaming. Can you point to the Shopify document explaining that header X-Shopify-Api-Features. I don't think there is any such thing. I get presentment data from normal API calls and therefore, I am super suspicious of this answer.

Comment: I am not sure, but try to remove extraHeaders: {
            'X-Shopify-Api-Features': 'include-presentment-prices',
          }。and you won't get the presentment price.

Comment: And many developers are using it, and you can find out more details on Shopify community.

Comment: I imagine it is benign. Does nothing. There are zero documentation entries for that. One forum post that used it, where the answer was different, does not make proof. Can you point to a single valid Shopify source for this?

Comment: Amazingly, it is not documented in shopify.dev, but I just confirmed that it works for the REST AdminAPI latest version 2023-07.  Here is a [Shopify Community Post](https://community.shopify.com/c/graphql-basics-and/we-have-prices-for-products-in-different-currencies-where-are/td-p/1496505) documenting it.   Without this special header, the presentment_prices are missing, regardless of whether or not you specify the presentment_currencies query parameter.